# scrolling in a command line interface

Tags: scroll, command-line, command-line-interface, command-prompt, uefi

If you have a large amount of output to a command line interface, how do you navigate upward to see the information that has already scrolled off the screen?

Is there common commands for this across various command line interfaces?

Comment: Depends on the terminal emulator basically. Shift + PGUP will work with many. But if you need the info, why not simply pipe it to a file or pass it to your next command? I'm unsure why `uefi` was tagged here.

Comment: @sammond do you mean UEFI Shell scrolling capability ?